# Jasper-Report server-side saving

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, jasper-reports

I have to make a JasperReport on serverside (Tomcat + gwt).
I try to run a hello-world

```
public class AuthorReport {
 public static void generate() {
try {
  String reportSource = "resources/authorReport.jasper";

  JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
    .compileReport(reportSource);

  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
    new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());

  JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "hello_report.html");


} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

I get no exceptions, but I cant realise where is the generated file and whether it is generated at all.

Maybe I do have to integrate somehow Tomcat and JasperReports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify this location in the second parameter of JasperFillManager.fillReport.

```
public class AuthorReport {

    public static void generate() {
        try {
           String reportSource = "resources/authorReport.jasper";

           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

           Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, new SimpleFileResolver(new File(youPath)));

           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

           JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, "hello_report.html");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: The path absolute or relative on your server side.